# Draw a parallel segment

Tags: java, python, c#, math, geometry

There are three main lines in my picture (AB, BC, BD) and three collateral ones, that are parallel to BD (CG, EH, FI); I know all the coordinates of A, B, C and D, I'm able to write the straight line equation, when there are two points that belong to the line. I need to model the movement of a segment, so that at t = 0 it's CD and at t = 1 it's the point B. The problem is that the segment has to be parallel to BD, and I don't know how to calculate the speed of the point on CB (for example, E) and the speed of the point on AB (for example, H), so that the segment (EH) remains parallel to BD. It means that I can't figure out the increments of the X-coordinates of the points, which I want to use in the timer. I've tried to use the cosine for CBA, to work with k factor (from the equation y = kx + b) for both parallel segments, to check some logical speculations, but everything was in vain: EH wasn't parallel to BD. Help me, please, to deal with this problem, it's very important for me.

Here is the illustration of the right program execution
[image]

Comment: It's all just proportions, right?  I assume you can compute the location of G.  Then, in unit time, the bottom point is moving length(GB) units per t, and the top point is moving length(CB) units per t.  So, at the halfway point, it's C - len(CB) / 2.  `Cx = Cx + t* (Bx-Cx)`, and `Cy = Cy + t*(By-Cy)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to go about this woult be to first compute the location of G (as mentioned by Tim Roberts in the comments) and then use the intercept theorem to calculate the distances CE and GH; etc.

[image: edited illustration]

To compute G an elegant way would be to find a Point D' on BC and a Point B' on AB such that `|B'D'| = |BD|` and B'D' is parallel to BD. The sine theorem in the triangle B'BD' implies that `|B'D'|/sin(beta) = |BD'|/sin(180-alpha)=|BB'|/sin(alpha - beta)`

`|B'D'| = |BD|` can be calculated and the angles alpha and beta are those between DBA and CBA respectively and thus can be calculated aswell.

Therefore you can compute |BD'| and |BB'|. You can now use the intersect theorem to calculate G,H,I, etc:
`|BD'|/|BB'| = |BC|/|BG| = |BE|/|BH|` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

def wedge2D(U, V):
  return U[0]*V[1] - U[1]*V[0]

def endpoints_of_segment(t, B, A, C, D):
  BA = A - B
  BC = C - B
  BD = D - B
  BG = (wedge2D(BC, BD)/wedge2D(BA, BD)) * BA  
  E = B + (1-t)*BC
  H = B + (1-t)*BG
  return E, H
```

A test example:

```
def load_points(A, B, C, D, E, H):
  M = np.array([[A[0],A[1]],[B[0],B[1]],
                [C[0],C[1]],[D[0],D[1]],
                [E[0],E[1]],[H[0],H[1]]])
  return M

def load_points3(X, Y, Z):
  M = np.array([
                [X[0],X[1]],
                [Y[0],Y[1]],
                [Z[0],Z[1]]])
  return M

A = np.array([0,0])
B = np.array([7,1])
D = np.array([5.7, 5])
C = np.array([3.5,4])


A = np.array([0,0])
B = np.array([7,1])
D = np.array([5.7, 5])
C = np.array([3.5,4])
t = 0.4
E, H = endpoints_of_segment(t, B, A, C, D)

M = load_points(A, B, C, D, E, H)
AHB = load_points3(A, H, B)
BEC = load_points3(B, E, C)
BD = load_points3(B, B, D)
EH = load_points3(E, E, H)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(AHB[:,0], AHB[:,1])
plt.plot(BEC[:,0], BEC[:,1])
plt.plot(BD[:,0], BD[:,1])
plt.plot(EH[:,0], EH[:,1])

for j in range(M.shape[0]):
   plt.plot(M[j,0], M[j,1], 'ro')
axx = plt.gca()
axx.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```